# laptop display shuts off soon after booting

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display

I wouldn't say it's shutting down because the laptop lights don't turn off and if I wait a while and touch the touchpad it will come back up - but not right away.

The weirdest thing is that it will do the same thing in BIOS so I assume it can't be a windows problem.

Windows 7 Home Premium on an older Dell D800.